# Flutter url_launcher ignores number sign(#) when call

Tags: android, flutter, dart, url-launcher

I'm using url_launcher in my app. When I dial numbers that includes a number sign like "*123#" it ignores the number sign and dial just *123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Uri.encodeComponent to encode # too

```
onPressed: () {
        String no = Uri.encodeComponent('*123#');
        launch('tel:$no');
      },
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked but I don't know why it was not working before.

Comment: Cheers mate, no problem. Because it is a special character, it should be encoded

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Uri.encodeComponent` to encode `#` your string

```
onPressed: () {
        String mycode = Uri.encodeComponent('*#06#');
        launch('tel:$mycode');
      },
```

Because special characters need to be encoded to be able to use by your device